# How to add background-image with pseudo before

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use one image for a list and each li will display different background position, but I can't even get the image to display.

```
#info li a:before {
background-image: url(img/about/Capture.png) no-repeat;
}

#info li:nth-child(1){
background-size:auto ;
background-position: 0% -6.9%;
}

#info li:nth-child(2){
background-size:auto ;
background-position: 0% 37%;
}

#info li:nth-child(3){
background-size:auto ;
background-position: 0% 73.4%;
}

#info li:nth-child(4){
background-size:auto ;
background-position: 0% 111%;
}
```

----EDIT----
i just realized i dont actually need any pseudo :P lol i can just do it like that :

```
#info li{
background: url("img/about/Capture.png") no-repeat ;
background-size:auto ;
}

#info li:nth-child(1){
background-position: 0 -6.9%;
}

#info li:nth-child(2){
background-position: 0 37%;
}

#info li:nth-child(3){
background-position: 0 73.4%;
}

#info li:nth-child(4){
background-position: 0 111%;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a pseudo element for this? Why not set the background image for the element itself?

Comment: Your syntax for `background-image: url(img/about/Capture.png) no-repeat;` is incorrect. You're mixing the syntax for the shorthand `background` property with `background-image`

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong, it should look like this.

```
#info li a:before {
    content: "";
    background: url(img/about/Capture.png) no-repeat;
}
```

On pseudo element you need to set the `content: ""` attribute for them to work.

You can't set `no-repeat` when using `background-image:`, you need `background:`.

You might also need width/height to make image visible.

**Edit 1**, on your comment: Here is 2 samples how you can do.

```css
a.link1:before {
  content: url(http://placehold.it/40x40);
}

a.link2 {
  position: relative;
}

a.link2:before {
  content: "";
  background: url(http://placehold.it/100x40) no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1
}
```

```html
<a class="link1" href="#">This is a link 1</a><br><br>
<a class="link2" href="#">This is a link 2</a>
```

**Edit 2**, on your post edit: Yes, of course you can set a background image on your `li` element.

Comment: @Moliere Updated with samples so you can see it does work.